# Unable to index into an object of type System.Xml.XPathNodeList

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, umbraco, umbraco7

**Visual Studio 2015 + Framework 4.5 + Nuget Package Manager console + Installing Umbraco7 by the command (Install-Package uCommerce.Umbraco7”)  = Getting following error:**

```
Unable to index into an object of type System.Xml.XPathNodeList.
At E:\ShopKart\packages\uCommerce.Umbraco7.8.0.0.18352\tools\install.ps1:59 char:129
+     $perRequestLifestyleHttpModulesElement = $webConfig.SelectNodes("//system.web//httpModules//add[@name='PerRequestLifestyle']")[
 <<<< 0]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

That package does not contain Umbraco 7, it contains UCommerce for Umbraco 7 :-/ Try Install-package UmbracoCms instead?